# Pass data to Directive in Angular 9

Tags: angular, directive

I create a directive include a component: **HomechildrenComponent**

```
<p>{{name}}</p>
<address>
  <strong>Twitter, Inc.</strong><br>
  1355 Market St, Suite 900<br>
  San Francisco, CA 94103<br>
  <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (123) 456-7890
</address>
```

and directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appRenderhomechildcp]'
})

export class RenderhomechildcpDirective {
  private name : string;
  @Input('appRenderhomechildcp') set appRenderhomechildcp(name : string){
    this.name = name;
  };

  childComponent : ComponentRef<HomechildrenComponent>;

  constructor(private container : ViewContainerRef, private cpFactoryResolve : ComponentFactoryResolver) 
  { 
    const componentFactory = this.cpFactoryResolve.resolveComponentFactory(HomechildrenComponent);
    this.childComponent = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.childComponent.instance.name = this.name;
    
  }
```

after i call the directive into Home.Component.ts

```
lsFood = ['Candy', 'Milk', 'Juice fruite', 'Cream']

<div *ngFor="let item of lsFood">
    <div [appRenderhomechildcp]="item"></div>
</div>
```

But it can not binding data from HomeComponent to directive. How can i handle it?
Thanks

Comment: Try moving the `constructor` code into `ngOnInit`, where you can be sure `this.name` is assigned.

Answer (score 3):

Your `@Input` property is not initialized yet in constructor. Move `name` initialization to [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) hook and it should work:

```
export class RenderhomechildcpDirective implement OnInit {
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.childComponent.instance.name = this.name;
  }
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/nGUReAiTrq3CZszInTgC)**